# Poisson process: Probability that $n$ busses of bus route A arrive before the first bus of route B

Tags: probability

> There are two bus routes that stop at a bus stop. Busses arrive according to a poisson process with rate $\lambda_1t$ buses per minute for the first route and $\lambda_2t$ for the second route.
>
> Find the probability that at least $n$ buses of route 1 will pass by berfor the first bus of route 2 arrives.
>
> Hint: You may use the fact that if $X_1 \sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda_2)$, then $P(X_1 < X_2) = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$.

I didn't know how to make use of the hint. I thought the following way:

Let $Z_1(t) \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda_1t)$ be the number of buses of route 1 that stop in a time interval of size $t$, and $Z_2(t) \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda_2t)$ the number of buses of route 2. Then we are looking for $P(Z_1 \geq n \cap Z_2=0)$:

\begin{align}
P(Z_1 \geq n \cap Z_2=0) &= \int_{t=0}^{t=\infty} P(Z_1 \geq n)(t) \cdot P(Z_2 = 0)(t) dt
\end{align}

And there I realize that I'm probably off the track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may already know that the time it takes for the first bus of route 1 to arrive is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_1$. Likewise, the arrival time of the other bus is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_2$. So, the hint tells you that the probability of the event "first bus to reach the bus stop is of route 1" is $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$. (Do you see why?)

Using other properties of Poisson processes, you can show that the probability of the event "the second bus to reach the bus stop is of route 1" is also $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$, and the similarly for the $n$th bus. Even more, these events are all independent! [You will need to justify these facts.] With this information, you can easily find the answer to your question.

The "merging" of two Poisson processes is called "superposition," in case you want to learn more about it.

Comment: Thank's for your comment. You said the events were all independent, but how can that be the case? If the first bus of route 2 arrives at time $t$, then the first bus of route 1 can arrive at any time between 0 and $t$, but the second bus of route 1 must arrive after the first. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: @Dominik No, I am not saying that the events "first bus of route 2 arrives at time $t$" and "second bus of route 2 arrives at time $t'$" are independent. I am saying that the events "first bus _is_ of route 1," "second bus _is_ of route 2," "third bus _is_ of route 3,", etc. are independent. [This is equivalent to imagining that the buses arrive without a label, and you flip a $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$-weighted coin to determine which route it will be.]

Comment: So basically the first bus arriving has probability $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$ of being from route 1. Then, due to the memoryless property of the exponential, the situation is reset and the probability of the second bus being of route 1 is the same. Then I can use the geometric distribution to answer the orginal question?

Comment: @Dominik Yes I think that's the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I will have to learn more about poisson processes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Poisson processes are independent, the successive routes are i.i.d. and route 1 has probability $p=\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$. Hence the $n$ first routes are all route 1 with probability $p^n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain to me why this answer should be $p^n$? I understand why $P(X_1 < X_2) = p$. But consider the second bus of the first route. It arrives after the first bus, so its arrival time should be the sum of two independent random variables. The way I understand your solution is that there are $n$ copies of route 1, the first buses of which arrive before the first bus of route 2.

Comment: These are well known independence properties of Poisson processes, hence, ultimately, of exponential random variables. As a kind of warm up, you could try to show that, if $U$, $V$ and $W$ are independent exponential, then $P(W\gt U+V)=P(W\gt U)P(W\gt V)$.